# Анимированный прогресс бар

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

Добрый вечер/день! Есть круглый прогресс бар, который имеет два режима "анимированный" и "не анимированный". Есть checkbox "Animate", который когда имеет "checked" он выполняет код верно, а когда он не выбран, то строится прогресс бар, как будто он выбран.
Вопрос вот в чём, как реализовать, чтобы круглый прогресс бар строился моментально в режиме без анимации. Заранее спасибо!
Есть подозрение, что код при данном режиме (без анимации), не видит функции, которые строят его без анимации.
Сам код `https://codepen.io/Mor_ner/pen/ooGayQ`

```js
var max = 100;

function isright(obj) {
  var anim = document.getElementById('onoffswitch').checked;
  var value = +obj.value.replace(/\D/g, '') || 0;
  if (value > 100) value = 100;
  if (value < 0) value = 0;
  obj.value = value;
  if (max = obj.value) {
    (startProcess() && anim) || (startProcessNoSim() && !anim); // При смене параметра Value, запускается новый процесс
  }
}
startProcess();

// Функция, которая очищает холст, рисует пустую шкалу прогресс бара, затем запускает новое построение
function startProcess() {
  emptyProgress();
  progressBar();
}
// Функция, которая очищает холст, рисует пустую шкалу прогресс бара, затем строит процесс без симуляции
function startProcessNoSim() {
  emptyProgress();
  progressBarNoSim();
}

function emptyProgress() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('bar').getContext('2d');
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(85, 85, 80, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#efefec";
  ctx.stroke();
}

function progressBar() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('bar').getContext('2d');
  var al = 0; // amount loaded = al, количество загрузки
  var start = -Math.PI / 2;
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  var diff;

  // Симуляция прогресса
  function progressSim() {
    diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(85, 85, 80, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffdb4d"; // Цвет фона
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.stroke();

    if (al >= max) {
      clearTimeout(sim);
      // Здесь располагаются процессы, которые потребуются по завершении симуляции прогресса
      // hideshow(); // К примеру
    }
    al++;
  }
  var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 30); // Время, за которое строится прогресс бар
}

function progressBarNoSim() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('bar').getContext('2d');
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  var start = -Math.PI / 2;
  var diff = max;

  function progressNoSim() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(85, 85, 80, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffdb4d"; // Цвет фона
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
// function animateBar() {
//  var anim = document.getElementById('onoffswitch').checked;
//  if(anim) {
//   startProcess();
//  } else {
//   startProcessNoSim();
//  }
// }
function hideshow() {
  var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
  if (bar.style.display != "none") {
    bar.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    bar.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font: 20px/24px Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

canvas {
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  left: 67px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 320px;
  height: 568px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.switchers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.progress__bar {
  /*animation: spin 3s linear; */
}


/* Стили api управления */


/* Value button */

.switchers__ios-btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 87px;
}

.switchers__ios-btn__number {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 48px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
}

.switchers__ios-btn__number-label {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}

.switchers__animate-label {
  position: relative;
  left: 63px;
  top: -17px;
}

.switchers__hide-label {
  position: relative;
  left: 63px;
  top: -33px;
}


/* ios button */

.switchers__onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  width: 48px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.switchers__onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.switchers__onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.switchers__onoffswitch-label:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.switchers__onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.switchers__onoffswitch-label {
  background-color: #49E845;
}

.switchers__onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.switchers__onoffswitch-label,
.switchers__onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.switchers__onoffswitch-label:before {
  border-color: #49E845;
}

.switchers__onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.switchers__onoffswitch-label:before {
  right: 0px;
}

.switchers__hideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 48px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.switchers__hideshow-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.switchers__hideshow-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.switchers__hideshow-label:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.switchers__hideshow-checkbox:checked+.switchers__hideshow-label {
  background-color: #49E845;
}

.switchers__hideshow-checkbox:checked+.switchers__hideshow-label,
.switchers__hideshow-checkbox:checked+.switchers__hideshow-label:before {
  border-color: #49E845;
}

.switchers__hideshow-checkbox:checked+.switchers__hideshow-label:before {
  right: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 568px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 568px;
    height: 320px;
  }
  .progress {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .switchers {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .switchers__ios-btn {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 67px;
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Progress bar</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> -->
  <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/minilogo.png"> -->
  <meta name="description" content="прототип прогресс бара, prototype progress bar" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="прототип, прогресс, бар, prototype, progress, bar" />
  <!-- css  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
      <p>Progress</p>
      <canvas id="bar" class="progress__bar" width="170" height="170"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="switchers" class="switchers">
      <div class="switchers__ios-btn">

        <input type="text" id="number" class="switchers__ios-btn__number" min="0" max="100" pattern="\d [0-100]" maxlength="3" value="100" onchange="isright(this)">
        <label class="switchers__ios-btn__number-label">Value</label>

        <div class="switchers__onoffswitch">
          <input type="checkbox" class="switchers__onoffswitch-checkbox" id="onoffswitch" onclick="isright(this)" checked>
          <label class="switchers__onoffswitch-label" for="onoffswitch"></label>
        </div>
        <label class="switchers__animate-label">Animate</label>
        <br>
        <div class="switchers__hideshow">
          <input type="checkbox" id="hideshowswitch" class="switchers__hideshow-checkbox" onclick="hideshow()">
          <label class="switchers__hideshow-label" for="hideshowswitch"></label>
        </div>
        <label class="switchers__hide-label">Hide</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Добавил к функции isright(obj)
<pre> var anim = document.getElementById('onoffswitch').checked;
if (max = obj.value) {
   (startProcess() && anim) || (startProcessNoSim() && !anim);
}<code>

https://codepen.io/Mor_ner/pen/ooGayQ

Предполагал что произойдёт выбор между запуском процесса, в котором строится с анимацией прогресс бар и без. Но и в данном случае строится не так, как ожидается.

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но возможно есть такой параметр animationEnableю Думаю его можно выключить, и анимация работать не будет